# Scheduler - override, GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, applet, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm writing something like scheduler (lesson plan).

[image]

As shown above, the text field is overwritten.
How can check if the coordinates x / y is someElement to avoid overwriting?

Comment: CAn you elaborate more. I don't understand your question.

Comment: _dodwawaniu 2 item in the same place you should add it_ Sorry I don't speak that language, so it's pretty hard to understand. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help, java language is "universal" (at least for us ;-)).

Comment: I want to protect the program before adding two elements in one place.